# Native Element function to focus is not working

Tags: angular

I was trying to autofocus on an input element on click of a button. Please see the typescript

```
@ViewChild('envFilter') envFilter: ElementRef;
onFilterSelect() {
    this.envFilter.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

On the HTML side I have the following.

```
<div [ngClass]="isFilterVisible ? 'item item1' : 'item item1 hide'">
     <div [@filterAnimation]="isFilterVisible" class="filterWrapper">
          <input type="text" class="envFilter" [(ngModel)]="envFilterValue" (keyup)="envFilterChanged(envFilterValue)" #envFilter />
            <!-- {{ envFilter.focus() }} -->
      </div>
</div>
```

On using `{{ envFilter.focus() }}` I'am able to focus on the field but I'm not able to focus on any other input boxes

Missed a small bit of HTML here

```
<div class="pull-right  filter-down filter-down-div item item2">
     <i *ngIf=" envs.length !=0" role="button" (click)="onFilterSelect(envFilter)" class="filter-icon fas fa-search"
            [ngClass]="{'active': isFilterVisible ,'disabled':!isFilterVisible}" role="button"></i>
</div>
```

This segment is basically a search button which on click calls the previous onFilterSelect() function

Is there some wrong in my code. Why is the auto-focus not working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know if your problem is this, but remember that if you have the input in a *ngIf, you need give Angular a "breath" (using, e.g. setTimeout)

A simple example, imagine you have

```
<input *ngIf="visible" [(ngModel)]="variable" #myInput>
<button (click)="focus()">click</button>
```

You have

```
visible:boolean=false
@ViewChild('myInput') myinput:ElementRef
```

If you write

```
/**NO WORK***/
focus()
{
  this.visible=true;
  this.myinput.nativeElement.focus() //<--NOT YET in the DOM
}
```

You need write something like

```
focus()
{
  this.visible=true;
  setTimeout(()=>{
      this.myinput.nativeElement.focus()
  })
}
```

This setTimeout, make that first repaint, and after, makes the focus

Comment: After much searching this was the only thing that worked. I love you, thank you. xD

Comment: Only this solution worked for me in Chrome. Firefox no problem, no timeout needed. Thanks :) Do You know maybe how to disable input tooltip ? It shows up as soon as I click inside input. It shows my recent inputs in this particular input field. I have this problem in Chrome. In Firefox no problem.

Answer (score -1):

You're not calling the `onFilterSelect` method anywhere. Did you mean to reference that instead of `envFilterChanged` in your `(keyup)` binding?

Comment: envFilterChanged is to read the changes in input and onFilterSelect is to show the field I made a change to the question