# Swap Focus Between Input Elements Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-directive

I have two input components

```
<ng-container *ngIf="isTextMode; else numericInputContainer">
  <app-text-input #textInput (keydown)="onInputKeyDown($event)">
  </app-text-input>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #numericInputContainer>
  <app-numeric-input #numericInput (keydown)="onInputKeyDown($event)">
  </app-numeric-input>
</ng-template>
```

Depending on the keystroke in the onInputKeyDown method, one field will disappear and the other will take its place. This functions correctly and they show and hide accordingly. However, I need to focus on the input that appears after the trigger.

Here is the method I am using that is called in the onInputKeyDown method:

```
  setFocus() {
    if (this.isTextMode) {

      let element = document.getElementById("textInput");
      if(element){
        element.focus();
      }
    }
    else {

      let element = document.getElementById("numericInput");
      if(element){
        element.focus();
      }
    }
  }
```

When debugging, the element appears to be **null** in both instances, even though it is visible in the DOM.

Is there a better way to programmatically set focus on the right element?

Comment: None of the elements in your DOM have an id named `textInput` or `numericInput`. What are you expecting? `.focus()` is definitely the way to focus your inputs, but you need to make sure to actually call it on a `HtmlInputElement` and not the `app-...-input` elements.

Comment: It would be good, if you provide the issue reproducible code in stackblitz

Comment: Oh apologies, thanks for pointing that out. I pulled some code out to anonymize it and I've taken out the ids. Thank you

Comment: `this.isTextMode` needed to be set somewhere! how are you setting value for `isTextMode`

Comment: Please see the stackBlitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eacqsq?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Here #numericInput & #textInput referring to components, not the exacts inputs, that's why you are getting null

Comment: The provided stackblitz is working as expected with little bit changes in textmode condition check

Comment: Can I refer to the components themselves instead @SivakumarTadisetti ?

Comment: the problem is that you need give Angular a "breath", (see this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62025095/native-element-function-to-focus-is-not-working/62026951#62026951)). Using viewChild your [forked stackblitz working](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kmr4wd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score -1):

1. if you want to refer element by id, you should use `id="test"` not `#test`, `#test` is to refer using @Viewchild.
2. Using `document.querySelector` is a very bad idea, if one day you are going to have several components of the same type on the page, that's not going to work. Use `elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector` at least.
3. Angular first run your methods and then updates DOM, so when you set `isTextMode` to false, DOM is not updated yet and there is no `numericInputContainer`. To make it work you can use `setTimeout` -- it gonna run after change detection, when your HTML is already updated.
4. Changing input type on keydown is very unnatural, I hope you should re-design that... Remember that users can copy-paste and drag-drop text to a text field and if at some point field is cleared user may be very surprised and disappointed.